# Netbeans, java, creating jar

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I originally had one project with just one class (called GetData) that worked well, and it had a main() method in it. Now, I got rid of the main method because I have to use this project as a library, and no matter what I do (yes, I went into properties), it won't generate a jar file that I can use! Is there a special way to do this? Also, I recently got Mercurial revision support on this project, so that might be a reason.

EDIT: I get "Finished building PROJECTNAME(clean, jar)" in the lower left hand corner when I do a clean build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that your project is called DataGetter.  You created the project by doing the following...

File->New Project and selected Categories: Java and Projects: Java Application on the New Projects dialog.

You have the Projects explorer open and it shows your project (DataGetter).

Select the Files item from the Window menu (control-2/clover-2 [on mac]).

A new explorer window will be displayed, titled Files.

You will see a 'node' labelled DataGetter, sort of like the node on the Projects explorer... but it has a different icon.

Expand that node and you will see a folder node labelled 'dist'. Expand that node to see your jar file, DataGetter.jar.

BONUS ANSWER:

If you are writing the application that will use this jar in NetBeans, you can make the DataGetter project a Library of the Application that you are developing.  Look for a node labelled Libraries underneath your new Application project's node in the Projects explorer window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a jar that you can click and run you need a main method somewhere for it run.  Library or not.

Comment: I don't need it to run, I want to import from it from another project which will have a main() method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error message when you try to build it? Make sure there's nothing in main that if taken out would prevent it from compiling.

Comment: If it says finished building then you should find the .jar in the dist folder of the project. You can then use that to import into other projects.